# PyInstaller bundles too many packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

So for my update module I have a progressbar system with tqdm.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
    for i in tqdm(range(3)):
        something()
```

I want my friends without python to use it, so I use PyInstaller. However, PyInstaller creates executables that are 50mb. I have used Py2EXE.net before, which gave me ~6-7MB .exe files. From the output log, I have guessed that it has decided to copy ALL of my site-packages, and I have about 200 packages.

How can I stop PyInstaller from copying all of my packages, and just copy tqdm?

## PyInstaller Log

[Pastebin Output](https://pastebin.com/BmiPKckY) (Log Output did not fit here.)

Comment: Can you provide the exact `pyinstaller` invocation you used?  In a [Pipenv](https://docs.pipenv.org) with `tqdm` installed, on MacOS 10.13.3, I get a 5MB file by running the following command: `pyinstaller --clean --onefile myscript.py`.  `tqdm` has some surprising `import` statements, [including iPython](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blob/master/tqdm/_tqdm_notebook.py#L23), which may account for the extra modules you're seeing.

Comment: @MaxShenfield i was using `pyinstaller myfile.py --onefile`

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this specific problem. Tqdm library uses other large modules. If you read the verbose you'll see how many modules is loading.
Effectively making your exe 50MB+~

Alternative with very light dependencies. You exe will be around 5MB provided no other large modules are imported by your script.
[progress module](https://pypi.org/project/progress/)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by making sure to run `pyinstaller` inside a virtual environment with all the required libraries included in.

Create and activate venv:

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

Install `pyinstaller` and required libraries inside the venv:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Then bundle:

```
pyinstaller myfile.py --onefile
```